# Can I install the mysql jdbc connector using mvn install:install-file?

Tags: mysql, maven, jdbc

I'd like to install the JDBC connector using maven.

I have the following: mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=mysql -DartifactId=mysql-connnector-java -Dversion=5.1.6 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile= -DgenerationPom=true

I think all I'm need is what I put on the other side of the =Dfile= ?

I haven't used maven in a while either, so I'm not sure what the file switch is used for?

Thanks for all the insight!

Comment: Why don't you use the `mysql:mysql-connector-java` from the Maven central repo? Anyhow I would like to prefer to use the `mvn deploy:deploy-file` instead as mentioning at http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html

Comment: I might have gotten install-file mixed up with deploy-file.  I'm basically looking for a way to get the mysql jdbc jar loaded into my maven repository.  I'm in the process of setting up a machine for Java development, and need to make sure I have access to the mysql DB first.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The "install-file" or "deploy-file" goals are used for installing or deploying artifacts to your local or internal repository that are not available from Maven Central or other external repositories that you may have configured.

If you've got access to Maven Central, simply adding the following to your project's pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

...should do the trick.

To answer your question though, the -Dfile= argument is for specifying the artifact that would actually be installed in the local repository.

Comment: Basically I plan to use maven for a planned project and would like to only have one copy of the mysql jdbc jar file on my machine and figured I should be able to pull it using a maven command.  How would I do that?

Comment: Yep, the above method of just adding it to your pom.xml will do just that. When it detects it is not in your local Maven repository (on your hard drive), it will load it from Maven Central. Subsequent requests from this or orher projects for it will use that JAR.

Comment: I've included this part in my `pom.xml`, and the code works as intended when running the code from IntelliJ. But when I run `mvn package`, the resulting jar file still complains about a missing jdbc driver. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

> lotz answer is right and that should be sufficient

But, If you want to use the latest version of the connector, you can check https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java

Add the following to your project's pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```